# Filtered list view not show up Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I tried make filtered list view but when I make it, the flitered return nothing. Please some one help me to solve it

this is my search text field

```
Container(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (stringToSearch) {
                    print(stringToSearch);
                    setState(() {
                      filteredList = data.where((u) => (
                          u.first_name.toLowerCase().contains(stringToSearch.toLowerCase()) ||
                          u.last_name.toLowerCase().contains(stringToSearch.toLowerCase()))
                      ).toList();
                    });
                    print(filteredList.toString());
                  },
                  controller: editingController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

This is my listview builder

```
child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:6, right: 6),
              itemCount: data.isEmpty ? 0 : data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                return Card(
                  elevation: 5,
                  color: data[index]['has_arrived']==0 ? Color(0xFFffb0b9) : Color(0xFF6bed96),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(data[index]['first_name']+' '+data[index]['last_name'], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                    subtitle:
                    Container(
                      child: (
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(data[index]['email']??'-', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: data[index]['has_arrived']==0 ?Color(0xFFa10618):Color(0xFF007326))),
                              Text(data[index]['order_reference']??'-', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white)),
                              Text(data[index]['phone_number']??'-', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white)),
                              Text(data[index]['school']??'-', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white)),
                            ],
                          )
                      ),
                    ),
                    trailing: 
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        var _inOut = data[index]['has_arrived']==0?'in':'out';
                        var _privateReferenceNumber = data[index]['private_reference_number'];
                        _loadCheckInOut(_privateReferenceNumber, _inOut);
                        },
                      child: Badge(
                        elevation: 5,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                        badgeColor: data[index]['has_arrived']==0 ? Color(0xFF1e9e49) : Color(0xFFd13446),
                        badgeContent: Text(data[index]['has_arrived']==0 ?'Present':'Absent', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                        toAnimate: false,
                        borderRadius: 20,
                        shape: BadgeShape.square,
                      ),
                    ),
                    isThreeLine: true,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

What should I do? `print(filteredList.toString());` return nothing. I want to make it simple and i dont want to make model

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why the filteredList returns nothing is because it is not in **setState**

Try

```
  setState(() {
    filteredList = data
        .where((u) => (u.first_name
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(stringToSearch.toLowerCase()) ||
            u.last_name.toLowerCase().contains(stringToSearch.toLowerCase())))
        .toList();
  });
```

Comment: the whole apps? my problem code is just what i posted